# Renaming ODBC query calls

Tags: ms-access

I have an old VB6 application which we do not have source code to edit. The application tries to open a table to a server but the table name has a period on it because the old provider allowed periods on table names. Now, we are trying to make a workaround using an MS ACCESS table. Problem is MS ACCESS do not allow periods on table names.

Our problem is that the VB6 application will request table name MAINDIR.ITEMSTABLE and it will return a TABLE NOT FOUND error because the table or query cannot be named on MS ACCESS with a period. Is there a way that we can do a VBA function that will trigger when an external ODBC call is made to the database that will see the incoming query and replace the table name? Like for example if th VB6 application sends an SQL query like:

SELECT * FROM DBNAME.TABLENAME

how can I make it refer (or modify the query) so that it returns

SELECT * FROM DBNAME_TABLENAME?

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Use MS SQL Server instead of MS Access. Then you can create a schema "MAINDIR" and not have to use work arounds. AFAIK There is a free edition of SQL Server for single user/small databases (so you do not have to worry about price).

Comment: I guess you could look at writing your own ODBC interface (assuming this is what the VB6 app uses). See [this MS page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710252(v=vs.85).aspx)